# Equations involving angle constraints

Tags: python, sympy, equation-solving

I'm trying to solve a system of equations using `sympy`.

```py
from sympy import *
def get_angles(a, b, c, d):
    theta, phi, lamb = symbols('\\theta \\phi \\lambda', real=True)
    a_eq = Eq(cos(theta / 2), a)
    b_eq = Eq(exp(I * phi) * sin(theta / 2), b)
    c_eq = Eq(-exp(I * lamb) * sin(theta / 2), c)
    d_eq = Eq(exp(I * (phi + lamb)) * cos(theta / 2), d)
    # theta_constr1 = Eq(theta >= 0)
    # theta_constr2 = Eq(theta <= pi)
    # phi_constr1 = Eq(phi >= 0)
    # phi_constr2 = Eq(phi < 2 * pi)
    res = solve([
        a_eq, b_eq, c_eq, d_eq,
        #theta_constr1, theta_constr2, phi_constr1, phi_constr2,
    ],
        theta,
        phi,
        lamb,
        check=False,
        dict=True)
    return res
```

The function returns the right results as it is, but it doesn't work if I try to put the constraint on the angles inside the system of equations (the commented parts). Is there any way to have them?

At the moment, I'm using a simple solution to overcome this limitation: I pass the result of the previous function to the following one to filter out unwanted results

```
def _final_constraint(result):
    res = []
    for sol in result:
        to_add = True
        for k, v in sol.items():
            if str(k) == '\\theta' and (v < 0 or v > pi):
                to_add = False
                break
            elif str(k) == '\\phi' and (v < 0 or v >= 2 * pi):
                to_add = False
                break
        if to_add:
            res.append(simplify(sol))
    return res
```

Comment: How do you invoke the function? I guess you pass numbers get_angles(1,2,3,4)

Comment: @yoelvis right, usually from a python shell

Answer (score 1):

`Eq` stands for `Equality` and is not an equation (though there is discussion of adding such an object to SymPy). So your uncommented `Eq` get interpreted as you intended, but the commented ones don't. You could try replacing `theta_constr1 = Eq(theta >= 0)` with `theta_constr1 = theta >= 0` but then you will run into problems with the the inequality solver -- it complains about there being more than one symbol of interest amongst the inequalities. So what about re-writing the inequalities like `x >= 0` as `Eq(x + eps, 0)` where `eps` is a nonnegative `Symbol`:

```
def get_angles(a, b, c, d):
    theta, phi, lamb = symbols('\\theta \\phi \\lambda', real=True)
    eps = Symbol('eps', nonnegative=True)
    a_eq = Eq(cos(theta / 2), a)
    b_eq = Eq(exp(I * phi) * sin(theta / 2), b)
    c_eq = Eq(-exp(I * lamb) * sin(theta / 2), c)
    d_eq = Eq(exp(I * (phi + lamb)) * cos(theta / 2), d)
    theta_constr1 = theta + eps
    theta_constr2 = pi - theta + eps
    phi_constr1 = phi  + eps
    phi_constr2 = 2 * pi - phi + eps
    res = solve([
        a_eq, b_eq, c_eq, d_eq,
        theta_constr1, theta_constr2, phi_constr1, phi_constr2,
        ],
        theta,
        phi,
        lamb,
        check=False,
        set=True)
    return res

>>> print(filldedent(get_angles(11,2,3,4)))

([\lambda, \phi, \theta], {(pi, 0, 4*pi - 2*acos(11)), (0, pi,
2*acos(11)), (0, pi, 4*pi - 2*acos(11)), (0, 0, 4*pi - 2*acos(11)),
(0, 0, 2*acos(11)), (pi, pi, 4*pi - 2*acos(11)), (pi, pi, 2*acos(11)),
(pi, 0, 2*acos(11))})
```

You would have to work out which side of `theta` and `phi` -- if any -- satisfied your equations.

Comment: However, your solution doesn't seem to work for, say, `get_angles(.5*sqrt(2), -0.5*sqrt(2)*I, -0.5*sqrt(2)*I, 0.5*sqrt(2)`. One of the result is `{\theta: 10.9955742875643, \lambda: 1.57079632679490, \phi: 1.57079632679490}`.

Comment: If you take out `check=False` the solutions will be checked and you will see that in this case there is no solution (if I am reading the results correctly). Either an Eq is false or eps would have to be negative when we required that it not be so.

Comment: Well, there is the solution `{\theta: pi/2, \lambda: pi/2, \phi: 3*pi/2}`, which is never returned if I'm using those constraints.

Comment: Hmm. Looks like you should just leave the auxiliary conditions off and filter your solutions to the other equations with those conditions. Answer has been updated to show that.